# Cambiar inicio de semana para ISO_WEEK DATEPART - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Necesito filtrar según el número de semana para lo cual entiendo se puede usar:

```
SELECT DATEPART(week, '20201227') --Número de semana 53
```

El problema de week es que la semana 53 termina en `31-12-2020`, ya que el primero día del `01-01-2021` es la semana 01 nuevamente.

Ya que necesitaba filtrar la semana 53 tanto para 2020 como 2021, es que vi la opción de usar `ISO_WEEK`

```
select DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '20201228') --Número de semana 53   28/12/2020
select DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '20210101') --Número de semana 53   01/01/2021
```

Mi problema es que ISO_WEEK usa al lunes como el primer día de la semana eso significa que si uso:

```
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK , '20201227') --Número de semana 52
```

Ya no es semana 53 si no 52, me gustaría saber si puedo cambiar el inicio de semana por el domingo y no lunes como lo tiene por defecto `ISO_WEEK`. Ya he intentado con:

```
set datefirst 7
select DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '20201227') --semana 52
```

Pero el problema persiste, muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

`ISO_WEEK` hace referencia al sistema europeo que se rige por ISO 8601. Cada semana se asocia al año en el que cae el jueves. `DATEFIRST` no le afecta.

Si quieres tomar otra referencia deberás hacerlo mediante `week`

```
SET DATEFIRST 7

SELECT  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '20201227') --semana 52
SELECT  DATEPART(week, '20201227') --semana 53
```