# Como puedo hacer un procedimiento almacenado para crear las Semanas de un año

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Hola tengo la siguiente tabla Semanas en SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE tblSemanas(
      SemanaID    BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      FechaInicio DATE NOT NULL,
      FechaFin    DATE NOT NULL,
      Anio        INT NOT NULL,
      SemanaNo    INT NOT NULL,
      UsuarioID   INT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT FK_IDUsuario FOREIGN KEY (UsuarioID) REFERENCES tblUsuarios (UsuarioID)
   );
```

Quiero hacer un procedimiento almacenado para crear todas las semanas de un año e insertarlas en la tabla, pasando por parametro el año teniendo en cuenta el estandar ISO para las semanas y tambien que el inicio de semana es Domingo, Por favor Agradeceria Su ayuda

Comment: Me parece que esto se relaciona: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/420441/cambiar-inicio-de-semana-para-iso-week-datepart-sql-server

Comment: ¿Qué es el problema para lo cual quieres ayuda? ¿No sabes como escribir un procedimiento almacenado? ¿O no sabes si es possible escribir ciclos en un procedimiento almacenado? ¿O buscas un SQL que produce una serie de datos?

Comment: Has intentado algo hasta ahora? por favor comparte lo que hayas probado así  la comunidad entiende que formas parte de la solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tus requerimientos son conceptualmente incompatibles. La norma ISO establece que una semana comienza el Lunes y la primera semana del año será la semana que contenga el primer jueves del año. El sentido de que contenga el primer jueves proviene del hecho que la semana que contenga el primer jueves tendrá al menos 4 días de ese año, es decir será de ese año por mayoría de días

Pero quien soy yo para contradecir a un hombre valiente que va contras las normas.

Para que resulte el asunto debemos establecer 2 puntos

- Diremos que la primera semana del año será la que tenga el 04 de Enero, esto es muy parecido a lo que hace la ISO
- Y la última semana será la que tenga el 28 de Diciembre

Entonces con:

- `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, 'año-01-04')` obtendremos `1`
- `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, 'año-31-28')` obtendremos `52` o `53` segun sea el caso

Luego usamos [GENERATE_SERIES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), para obtener una secuencia para recorrer las semanas

Algo así:

```
set datefirst 7;
DECLARE @year int = 2024
DECLARE @inicio DATETIME = CONCAT(@year , '-01-04');
SELECT 
    DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, F.fecha)  as SemanaNo,
    DATEADD(dd, @@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(dw, F.fecha) - 6, F.fecha) as FechaInicio,
    DATEADD(dd, @@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(dw, F.fecha), F.fecha) as FechaFin,
    @year as Anio
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, value*7, @inicio) as fecha /* Vamos generando una fecha como punto de referencia de cada semana*/
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, datepart(ISO_WEEK,CONCAT(@year , '-12-28'))-1) /* generamos una serie desde 0 hasta la cantidad de semanas del año -1 */
    
) as F
```

[DEMO ONLINE](https://onecompiler.com/sqlserver/3zytfkyrp)

Comment: Hola es cierto tienes razón tenia mal los requerimientos, solo ocupo que la semana inicie en domingo, Revise los resultados del demo y creo que haria falta la semana 53 ya que este año cuenta con 53 semanas

Comment: *contenga en vez de contenta

Comment: @KevinMunguia 52 semanas tiene este año https://www.calendario-365.es/calendario-2024.html